# Read Special Character like Register trademark

Tags: php, symbols

I use following statement for read the value and its works well.

`$PlaceName=$_REQUEST['PlaceName'];`

but here is one problem with above statement. If we pass some special type character (like Burger King ®), then variable $PlaceName contains blank value. Note that the reason of this problem is the symbol of registered trademark (®)

So how can I read this type of symbol in PHP by correcting above statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$PlaceName= "Burger King ®" ;
echo $PlaceName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your encoding, make sure your output is set to `utf8`.

I just tested this code and output was valid.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<hr />';
    echo $name;
}
```