# string's result is different after load in domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to have same result after load in domdocument. how to do it?

```
echo "Café"; 

$s = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Café
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$d = new domdocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);

echo $d->textContent;
```

first echo's result is = Café
second echo's result is =CafÃ©

Comment: Do you have proper encoding on your? Try UTF-8.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980207/read-special-character-like-register-trademark/12980275#12980275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your HTML as UTF-8 encoded

```
$s = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
Café
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$d = new domdocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);

echo $d->textContent;
```

Comment: You should test this your self

Comment: His page and php file is not saved in UTF-8 encoding, while the `DomDocument` is assuming utf-8. This will obviously work for anyone that has set page and php file encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: @Baba: I did that. Any specific reason you are doubting this will not work?

Comment: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! in Entity, line: 6 in `

Comment: try it in the browser not the shell. Also what is being displayed on the shell is a warning not an error. I tried it from the shell and after the warning the word prints fine.

Comment: Tested on another server it works ...... I guess it has to do with the system configuration

Comment: I am also facing warning that BABA tell
I am using wamp and i can't add mata tag because i am scraping this data

Comment: In that case use @Baba's solution he has provided (see the link to his answer). Set the header. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of the script and it should do the trick.

Comment: THanks it's working now after adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 1):

your problem is Encoding,
 for the First Echo, you echo the text with your default encoding,
but for the text randered through the DOMDocument,
the e+apostroph is split into two chars,

i dont know how to enforce the right encoding to DOMDoc...
**but i am sure this is your problem**

hope i helped, 
best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

With First echo before HTML you send HEADERS with your server default encoding. This ignores any next set encodings..
You must first echo

```
<Html tag and encodings etc..
```

and than echo any other values..